# python import fastparquet got "double free or corruption (top)" error

Tags: python, glibc, fastparquet

When I run `import fastparquet` I got error

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fastparquet
double free or corruption (top)
```

I didn't got this error yesterday. I tried to pip uninstall and install fastparquet again doesn't solve the problem.

The only clue I can think of is that I was trying to upgrade my glibc to version2.28 on ubuntu 18.04 today. But I failed with several methods. And now I still got glibc 2.27 on my ubuntu.

If `double free or corruption` is related to glibc, how could I fix it?

Comment: Maybe it is an error in the module?

Comment: @JCWasmx86 Hi, thank you for comment. That is not gonna be true. I use it everyday, it just broken today

Comment: I just solved the problem by upgrading ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04

Comment: "And now I still got glibc 2.27 on my ubuntu." -- it is very likely that you screwed up your system and left it partially updated. Glad complete upgrade fixed it for you. For future: upgrading GLIBC from one that was included in the distribution is a very fast way to render the system unbootable.